# Social.framework not found

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk, linker

I'm trying to link Facebook SDK 3.1 with my existing iOS application. Base SDK is 6.1, iOS Deployment Target is set to 5.1.

I added Social, Accounts and AdSupport framework to the project and set them to Optional in the Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries. I also tried to manually link them with -weak_framework in "Other Linker Flags".

However, I always end up with:

```
ld: framework not found AdSupport
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Using XCode version 4.6 by the way!

Comment: What about this error leads you to believe that the Social Framework wasn't found?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand your question... :x The ld error mentions that the framework could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the social framework is new in iOS6, if you are supporting iOS5 you has to go to your Target Properties/Build Phases/Link Binary with Libraries and mark the Social framework as Optional as shown in the image

[image: Mark framework as optional]

Comment: you have to do this for AdSupport and Accounts too, not only for Social

Comment: Yes, I made for all three... It works for Accounts but not for AdSupport nor Social... :(

Comment: it is strange, with this setting I'm able to build my apps, check the accepted answer of this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299474/how-to-integrate-facebooks-mobile-ad-functionality-in-our-app-that-supports-ios), maybe this helps you

Comment: Wow, that actually worked! I had done the cleaning before and it didn't work since I didn't delete the DerivedData, thank you so much! I will mark your answer as the solution, mostly due to your latest comment! :)

Comment: where do I find this setting? I take it it's in XCode somewhere.

Comment: it is in the properties of your target. Select the top group that is named as your project, then in the Editor Panel select the target (not the project) and in the tab Build Phases you will find it